# NVIDIA Jetson Nano with Realsense 435i via Isaac - Camera not found

Tags: robotics, nvidia-jetson, realsense, slam, nvidia-jetson-nano

I posted about this over on the Isaac forums, but listing it here for visibility as well. I am trying to get the Isaac Realsense examples working on a Jetson Nano with my 435i (firmware downgraded to 5.11.15 per the Isaac documentation), but I've been unable to so far. I've got a Nano flashed with Jetpack4.3 and have installed all dependencies on both the desktop and the Nano. The realsense-viewer works fine, so I know the camera is functioning properly and is being detected by the Nano. However, when I run `./apps/samples/realsense_camera/realsense_camera` it throws an error:

```
ERROR engine/alice/components/Codelet.cpp@229: Component 'camera/realsense' of type 'isaac::RealsenseCamera' reported FAILURE:

    No device connected, please connect a RealSense device
ERROR engine/alice/backend/event_manager.cpp@42: Stopping node 'camera' because it reached status 'FAILURE'
```

I've attached the log of this output as well. I get the same error running locally on my desktop, but that's running through WSL so I was willing to write that off. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.620 INFO  engine/alice/tools/websight.cpp@166: Loading websight...0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.621 WARN  engine/alice/backend/application_json_loader.cpp@174: This application does not have an explicit scheduler configuration. One will be autogenerated to the best of the system's abilities if possible.0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.622 INFO  engine/alice/backend/redis_backend.cpp@40: Successfully connected to Redis server.
0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.623 WARN  engine/alice/backend/backend.cpp@201: This application does not have an execution group configuration. One will be autogenerated to the best of the systems abilities if possible.0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.623 WARN  engine/gems/scheduler/scheduler.cpp@337: No default execution groups specified. Attempting to create scheduler configuration for 4 remaining cores. This may be non optimal for the system and application.0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.623 INFO  engine/gems/scheduler/scheduler.cpp@290: Scheduler execution groups are:0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.623 INFO  engine/gems/scheduler/scheduler.cpp@299: __BlockerGroup__: Cores = [3], Workers = No0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.623 INFO  engine/gems/scheduler/scheduler.cpp@299: __WorkerGroup__: Cores = [0, 1, 2], Workers = Yes0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.660 INFO  engine/alice/backend/modules.cpp@226: Loaded module 'packages/realsense/librealsense_module.so': Now has 45 components total0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.679 INFO  engine/alice/backend/modules.cpp@226: Loaded module 'packages/rgbd_processing/librgbd_processing_module.so': Now has 51 components total0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.696 INFO  engine/alice/backend/modules.cpp@226: Loaded module 'packages/sight/libsight_module.so': Now has 54 components total0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.720 INFO  engine/alice/backend/modules.cpp@226: Loaded module 'packages/viewers/libviewers_module.so': Now has 83 components total0m
90m2020-06-15 17:18:20.720 DEBUG engine/alice/application.cpp@348: Loaded 83 components: isaac::RealsenseCamera, isaac::alice::BufferAllocatorReport, isaac::alice::ChannelMonitor, isaac::alice::CheckJetsonPerformanceModel, isaac::alice::CheckOperatingSystem, isaac::alice::Config, isaac::alice::ConfigBridge, isaac::alice::ConfigLoader, isaac::alice::Failsafe, isaac::alice::FailsafeHeartbeat, isaac::alice::InteractiveMarkersBridge, isaac::alice::JsonToProto, isaac::alice::LifecycleReport, isaac::alice::MessageLedger, isaac::alice::MessagePassingReport, isaac::alice::NodeStatistics, isaac::alice::Pose, isaac::alice::Pose2Comparer, isaac::alice::PoseFromFile, isaac::alice::PoseInitializer, isaac::alice::PoseMessageInjector, isaac::alice::PoseToFile, isaac::alice::PoseToMessage, isaac::alice::PoseTree, isaac::alice::PoseTreeJsonBridge, isaac::alice::PoseTreeRelink, isaac::alice::ProtoToJson, isaac::alice::PyCodelet, isaac::alice::Random, isaac::alice::Recorder, isaac::alice::RecorderBridge, isaac::alice::Replay, isaac::alice::ReplayBridge, isaac::alice::Scheduling, isaac::alice::Sight, isaac::alice::SightChannelStatus, isaac::alice::Subgraph, isaac::alice::Subprocess, isaac::alice::TcpPublisher, isaac::alice::TcpSubscriber, isaac::alice::Throttle, isaac::alice::TimeOffset, isaac::alice::TimeSynchronizer, isaac::alice::UdpPublisher, isaac::alice::UdpSubscriber, isaac::map::Map, isaac::map::ObstacleAtlas, isaac::map::OccupancyGridMapLayer, isaac::map::PolygonMapLayer, isaac::map::WaypointMapLayer, isaac::navigation::DistanceMap, isaac::navigation::NavigationMap, isaac::navigation::RangeScanModelClassic, isaac::navigation::RangeScanModelFlatloc, isaac::rgbd_processing::DepthEdges, isaac::rgbd_processing::DepthImageFlattening, isaac::rgbd_processing::DepthImageToPointCloud, isaac::rgbd_processing::DepthNormals, isaac::rgbd_processing::DepthPoints, isaac::rgbd_processing::FreespaceFromDepth, isaac::sight::AliceSight, isaac::sight::SightWidget, isaac::sight::WebsightServer, isaac::viewers::BinaryMapViewer, isaac::viewers::ColorCameraViewer, isaac::viewers::DepthCameraViewer, isaac::viewers::Detections3Viewer, isaac::viewers::DetectionsViewer, isaac::viewers::FiducialsViewer, isaac::viewers::FlatscanViewer, isaac::viewers::GoalViewer, isaac::viewers::ImageKeypointViewer, isaac::viewers::LidarViewer, isaac::viewers::MosaicViewer, isaac::viewers::ObjectViewer, isaac::viewers::OccupancyMapViewer, isaac::viewers::PointCloudViewer, isaac::viewers::PoseTrailViewer, isaac::viewers::SegmentationCameraViewer, isaac::viewers::SegmentationViewer, isaac::viewers::SkeletonViewer, isaac::viewers::TensorViewer, isaac::viewers::TrajectoryListViewer, 0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.723 WARN  engine/alice/application.cpp@164: The function Application::findComponentByName is deprecated. Please use `getNodeComponentOrNull` instead. Note that the new method requires a node name instead of a component name. (argument: 'websight/isaac.sight.AliceSight')0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.723 INFO  engine/alice/application.cpp@255: Starting application 'realsense_camera' (instance UUID: 'e24992d0-af66-11ea-8bcf-c957460c567e') ...0m
90m2020-06-15 17:18:20.723 DEBUG engine/gems/scheduler/execution_groups.cpp@476: Launching 0 pre-start job(s)0m
90m2020-06-15 17:18:20.723 DEBUG engine/gems/scheduler/execution_groups.cpp@485: Replaying 0 pre-start event(s)0m
90m2020-06-15 17:18:20.723 DEBUG engine/gems/scheduler/execution_groups.cpp@476: Launching 0 pre-start job(s)0m
90m2020-06-15 17:18:20.723 DEBUG engine/gems/scheduler/execution_groups.cpp@485: Replaying 0 pre-start event(s)0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.723 INFO  engine/alice/backend/asio_backend.cpp@33: Starting ASIO service0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.727 INFO  packages/sight/WebsightServer.cpp@216: Sight webserver is loaded0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:20.727 INFO  packages/sight/WebsightServer.cpp@217: Please open Chrome Browser and navigate to http://<ip address>:30000m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.727 WARN  engine/alice/backend/codelet_canister.cpp@225: Codelet 'websight/isaac.sight.AliceSight' was not added to scheduler because no tick method is specified.0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.728 WARN  engine/alice/components/Codelet.cpp@53: Function deprecated. Set tick_period to the desired tick paramater0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.728 WARN  engine/alice/backend/codelet_canister.cpp@225: Codelet '_check_operating_system/isaac.alice.CheckOperatingSystem' was not added to scheduler because no tick method is specified.0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.728 WARN  engine/alice/components/Codelet.cpp@53: Function deprecated. Set tick_period to the desired tick paramater0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.730 WARN  engine/alice/components/Codelet.cpp@53: Function deprecated. Set tick_period to the desired tick paramater0m
1;31m2020-06-15 17:18:20.741 ERROR engine/alice/components/Codelet.cpp@229: Component 'camera/realsense' of type 'isaac::RealsenseCamera' reported FAILURE:

    No device connected, please connect a RealSense device
0m
1;31m2020-06-15 17:18:20.741 ERROR engine/alice/backend/event_manager.cpp@42: Stopping node 'camera' because it reached status 'FAILURE'0m
33m2020-06-15 17:18:20.743 WARN  engine/alice/backend/codelet_canister.cpp@225: Codelet 'camera/realsense' was not added to scheduler because no tick method is specified.0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:21.278 INFO  packages/sight/WebsightServer.cpp@113: Server connected / 10m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:30.723 INFO  engine/alice/backend/allocator_backend.cpp@57: Optimized memory CPU allocator.0m
0m2020-06-15 17:18:30.724 INFO  engine/alice/backend/allocator_backend.cpp@66: Optimized memory CUDA allocator.0m
```